# R - Export line by line while transforming data, adding "" in places and not others while also removing NA

Tags: r, export, export-to-csv, na

I am a rookie with R but I have a requirement to export data from a data.table to a CSV however I need to add a header and footer row and transform the data in the process.

The route that I have gone down is via sink and cat. This allows me to generate the header and footer lines and dump the 30000+ row data.table to the CSV via a_ply.

```
sink(filelocation)
cat("\"EX1\",1,\"EX2\",",time,sep="") #header
cat("\n")
a_ply(datatable1, 1, function(x){
cat("\"L1\",")
cat(paste(x, collapse=","))
cat("\n")
}) 
cat("\"EX3\",",EX4, sep="") #footer
sink()
```

I have all of that working perfectly however the part that I am struggling with is that I need to transform the data that is held in the data table. There is a requirement to have some columns in the data table exported as "Value", while leaving others as Value. There is also a requirement to remove NA values leaving them either as ,"", or simply as nothing ,,.

e.g.

This line

```
SystemID    UserID      Age Active  Status  LastAccess  LastAccessTime  Count
1234567     852741      39  Y       1       NA          NA             12
```

Currently exports as

1234567,852741,39,Y,1,NA,NA,12

Although I need it to be exported as

1234567,"852741",39,"Y",1,,"",12

The data.tables that I need to export are 30000+ long so was wondering if there is a better route to go down with this or how to structure the code to transform each line on the fly  and then cat that line to the file and move onto the next line.

I can't change the system that these files are going into so unfortunately I have to deal with the rigid nature of the data file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I think the function write.table() does everything you want.

Rather than "transforming" your data as you write it, cant you just modify the dataframe until it has the format you want?  For example, to get the UserID column to write out as a string, just convert that column to strings before writing the table, e.g.

```
myData$UserID<-as.character(myData$UserID)
```

Once the dataframe is correctly formatted, it should be as easy as

```
write.table(myData,outFilePath,sep=",",na="",row.names=FALSE)
```

Note the na="" argument, which tells it how to format NA values.  For the footer row, you could deal with that separately, and use the "append=TRUE" argument.

Comment: OK. I'll investigate this and see if I can come up with a solution. Do you know if it is possible to treat integer/numeric NA differently to character NA?

Comment: You can change the character NAs to an empty string.  It looks like you have `LastAccessTime` as a string, and you want to write it as an empty string with quotes.  So try replacing the character NAs in your source dataframe like this `myData$LastAccessTime[is.na(myData$LastAccessTime)]>=''` Then you will probably want to use the `quote=TRUE` argument in `write.table()` to make sure the quotes get written out.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm getting closer and closer to the solution needed. However I tried replacing the NAs in the dataframe by using the code provided however it didn't change anything.

Comment: Whoops.....Looks like there is a typo in my comment, try `myData$LastAccessTime[is.na(myData$LastAccessTime)]<-''`. I would edit it if I could.